# How to hide resolution status in chrome webview?

Tags: android, google-chrome, cordova

I'm using Cordova to build app in Android 4.4, which uses Chrome webview. When there is a window resize event (e.g. show soft keyboard), there will be a resolution label appear at the top-right corner. How to get rid of that?

(Attached is the effect shown in Chrome's device emulation page, which is basically the same)

[image: chrome resolution status]